# Filter array of objects in react native based on two conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have array of objects as follow:

```
[
    {
        "category": "Drinks",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "COLA",
        "price": 0,
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "category": "Drinks",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "COFFEE",
        "price": 2.5,
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "category": "Addons",
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Extra cheese",
        "price": 5,
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "category": "Addons",
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Extra vagg",
        "price": 3,
        "type": 0
    },

]
```

I want to filter the data based on category name and type so the data that have same category name and same type number become together, the result be something like

```
[
   Drinks:[
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "COLA",
              "price": 0,
              "type": 1
            },
            {
             "id": 2,
             "name": "COFFEE",
             "price": 2.5,
             "type": 1
            }
          ],
    Addons:[
            {
             "id": 3,
             "name": "Extra cheese",
             "price": 5,
             "type": 0
            },
            {
             "id": 4,
             "name": "Extra vagg",
             "price": 3,
             "type": 0
            }
           ]
  ]
```

note that category names not always the same names as above.
Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=Filter+OR+group+array+of+objects+based+on+conditions+site%3Astackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: There is nothing React about filtering or grouping